# empty request parameter in URL gives me cannot find API error

Tags: node.js, express

My code is :

```
xyz.js

const testFunction = (req, res) => {
    req.checkParams('xyz_name', 'Invalid name').notEmpty();
    req.sanitize('xyz_name').trim();

    const errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.json({
            status: '500',
            message: errors
        });
    } else {

        res.json({
            status: '200',
            message: 'list',
            data: req.params.xyz_name
        });
    }
};


module.exports = testFunction;
```

app.js

```
app.get('/test/xyz/:xyz_name', test);
```

When I try `http://localhost:3000/test/xyz/abc`, it works fine. But when I type `http://localhost:3000/test/xyz`, it give me error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot GET /test/xyz</pre>
    </body>
```

Is there anything, I am missing in my code to make it work?

Comment: If ‘xyz_name’ is optional it needs ‘?’ after it

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you provide this as an answer, so that It can help future readers?

Comment: Just did! Glad it helped!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an optional parameter in Express.js you need to designate it with a `?`.

`/test/xyz/:xyz_name` will match `/test/xyz/test` but not `/test/xyz`. This is basically setting `xyz_name` to a required parameter. If nothing is provided it will fail.

Whereas `/test/xyz/:xyz_name?` will match `/test/xyz/test` and `/test/xyz`. This is setting `xyz_name` to an optional parameter. If nothing is provided the route will still be hit.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your route is configured to require the `xyz_name` parameter.  Since it is not provided it cannot find a proper route match, this is expected.

If you'd like for your route to handle the request whether the parameter is provided or not, I believe you'll have to make the parameter optional like so:

```
app.get('/test/xyz/:xyz_name?', test);
```